# dropdown text gets empty when selecting datetime value in react

Tags: reactjs, datetime

I'm fairly new to reactjs world.
i have this problem where if select menuitem 2 which has value as datetime then in dropdown text it displays blank with no text on it.
while works fine when selecting menuitem 1.
can someone please tell me what's going on here ?

```
handleChange (event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value:value});
}

<DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} >
    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="2 Hour" />
   <MenuItem value={Datetime.monent()} primaryText="8 Hours" />
</DropDownMenu>
```